# JList selection changed

Tags: java, swing, listener, jlist

I'm using Netbeans to create a JList and an event listener. 
I want to retrieve the object the user selected, when it's selected.
So far I've got this:

```
private void listKurserValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {
    System.out.println("" + ((listKurser)evt.getSource()));
}
```

However, I'm getting "cannot find symbol" at listKurser, which is the JList.

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you show code how `ActionListener` with `listKurserValueChanged()` is being registered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
private void listKurserValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {
    System.out.println("" + ((JList)evt.getSource()));

    JList changedList = (JList)evt.getSource();
    if (listKurser == changedList) {
        //listKurser was changed
    }
}
```

Comment: @PatrickReck, what do you mean by does not work? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Oh, i didn't see your extended answer.
It says "cannot find symbol" @ all the JList

Answer (score 0):

Just to preface, I don't use Netbeans, but when I see the line:

```
private void listKurserValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {
```

I'm guessing that Netbeans auto-generated that method to be called from the ListSelectionListener that was attached to your JList called "listKurser".

Therefore, it's a unique listener that's attached only to that particular JList, which isn't necessarily a bad thing.  If so, there's no need to cast, or even call event.getSource().  Just simply call:

```
listKurer.getSelectedValue() //or whatever you're trying to call
```